# Не работает удаление SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
public override int Delete(Customer entity)
    {
        int updateResult = 0;
        DataRow[] rowForDelete = Table.Select($"{nameof(entity.Id)} = '{entity.Id}'");
        foreach (var row in rowForDelete)
        {
            Table.Rows.Remove(row);
        }
        updateResult = _adapter.Update(Table);
        return updateResult;
    }
```

хотя запрос Builder генерирует вполне нормальный:

```
DELETE FROM [main].[sqlite_default_schema].[Customer] WHERE (([Id] = @param1) AND ([Surname] = @param2) AND ([Name] = @param3) AND ([Patronymic] = @param4) AND ([Passport] = @param5) AND ([MobilePhone] = @param6) AND ([Email] = @param7))
```

Comment: Все колонки заполнены? Ни одна не равна `NULL`?

Comment: все, проверял через отлов

Comment: Все исправил нужно было просто : row.Delete();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove, оказывается, вызывает метод AcceptChanges и DataAdapter думает что ничего удалять не нужно, поэтому :

Вместо

```
 Table.Rows.Remove(row);
```

Нужно

```
row.Delete();
```

Comment: По-моему гораздо проще работать с базой через [SQLite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net)